# How to configure request timeout to trigger "connection cannot be established" error

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm testing the behaviour of my application when it tries to reach an unknown URL. It takes 5 seconds to raise a ConnectionError. How can I modify to fail, let's say, at 100ms instead?

I have tried setting the `timeout` parameter with `requests.get(url, timeout=0.1)`, but it changes nothing.

```
        try:
            requests.get(url, timeout=0.1)
        except Exception as error:
            return False
```

Comment: Your call looks right. But as-is, the try/except code jumps over the usual exception ("'Connection to github.com timed out. (connect timeout=0.1)'") and just returns false. So it might help to see what code calls this function.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was Docker and not the http library. Outside Docker it works properly.

Comment: Docker was trying to find a service (the url was like `http://offline_service:25000` with that name and take times to figure out the dns. Adding a `.com` (`offline_service.com:25000`) it figures out that the url is not internal to the docker network and sends the request outside, giving a normal connectionError in less than 100ms

Comment: Interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @Neil at the end was not fault of the Docker but the alpine image we were usign